# How can i find the depth of an branch in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to implement a function that gives me the depth of every branch from a tree and pack the integers of the depth in a list.
I know how I can find the maximum and the minimum, but I don't know how to find the other ones.

My code with an example tree:

Init my tree:

```
data NBaum a = NBlatt a | NKnoten a [NBaum a]
  deriving(Eq,Show)
```

Example tree:

```
NKnoten "Sonne"[NKnoten "Jupiter" [NBlatt "Io", NBlatt "Europa", NBlatt "Ganymed", NBlatt "Kallisto"],NKnoten "Mars" [NBlatt "Phobos", NBlatt "Deimos"],NBlatt "Merkur", NBlatt "Venus", NKnoten "Erde" [NBlatt "Mond"]]
```

Maximum depth:

```
tdepth (NBlatt a) = 1
tdepth (NKnoten _ b) = 1 + maximum [tdepth branch | branch <- b]
```

Minimum depth:

```
tdepth (NBlatt a) = 1
tdepth (NKnoten _ b) = 1 + minimum [tdepth branch | branch <- b]
```

The solution for the example tree, which I will have: `[2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]`. The elements of the lists can have another order.

Answer (score 1):

I left the recursive call unimplemented perhaps this shell may help:

```
depths :: (Num b) => NBaum a -> [b]
depths = go 1
  where
    go n (NBlatt _) = [n]
    go n (NKnoten _ xs) = error "depths.go: not implemented"
```

Comment: I know that i implement a recursive call wich calc n+1 and then recursive call with the xs list. But the exact call... I dont know

Comment: Can u help me ryachza ?

Comment: @Fl4mer Nykros answer is almost exactly what I had myself. Call `go (n+1)` with each element of `xs` and concatenate the results.

Comment: @Fl4mer Happy to help. If my answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you want to work out the solution for yourself, but here’s a hint: have you written an in-order or depth-first traversal function yet?

You can give your traversal function another parameter that remembers the depth.  Each recursive call increments it.  Instead of adding the contents of the node to the list, add the depth.

If you haven’t gotten to that yet, a good way to write that function is to add an accumulating parameter that constructs the list.  You start at the root with an empty list and depth 1, and each time you hit a leaf node, you append the current depth to the end of the list.  At a parent node, you concatenate the current depth with the lists you get back from calling the function on the daughters.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check it out. The idea is that the same function is applied to each of the substrees in the `NKnoten`, and the results are joined in a single list using `concat`.

```
depths :: (Num b) => NBaum a -> [b]
depths = go 1
  where
    go n (NBlatt _) = [n]
    go n (NKnoten _ xs) = concat (map (go (n+1)) xs)
```